# Cannot delete target directory after removing Maven nature of project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I decided not to use maven in my project. So, I right-clicked it in Eclipse and then "Remove maven nature". Everything seems to be ok, but I cannot remove the target directory. If I delete it from within Eclipse it's just created again, if I delete it from Explorer the result is the same, as soon as I clean my project from Eclipse it's just created again.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## To disable & remove Maven *target* directory

1. Right click on the project -select `Maven->Disable Dependency Management.`
2. Right click on project - select `Build Path-> Configure Build Path -> Source Tab`. Untick "*Allow output folder for source folders*"
3. Now type "Your Project Name"/bin eg. TestProject/bin, in the *Default Output Folder* field to point to default.
4. Now click ok and delete the target directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Right-click on project folder -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source
Change folder in 'Default output folder:' section to point new location.

Comment: Well, actually it was already done. What I did was untick "Allow output folder for source folders".

Answer (score 1):

`target/classes` directory is just as good as any one else. Since m2e switched this, it's Maven standard output directory, not related or handled by m2e anymore. If you want, you can set own output directory by project's `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Default output folder`, for example to `bin` directory which is Eclipse' default.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on you project.
Go to Build Path--> Configure Build Path
Uncheck Maven Dependencies, this made my target folder to work fine.